# Can anyone help with this probability question?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

n balls are arranged in n boxes (the balls are distinguishable and each box can accommodate any number of balls). What is the probability that exactly one box stays empty? The answer is $$n!(n-1)\over 2n^{n-1}$$ I don't know how this is. I tried solving it like this:$$P(A)={|A|\over |O|} ;  O=\{x_{1},x_{2},...:x_{1}+...+x_{n}=n\};;|A|=n|B|$$$$;B=\{x_{1},x_{2},...:x_{1}+...+x_{n-1}=n\}$$
Didn't get the same answer..

Comment: The probability that at least one box stays empty, or the probability that exactly one box stays empty?

Comment: exactly one stays empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having exactly one box empty can be realised in the following way:

1. First choose the box that will stay empty: that makes $n$ possibilities.
2. Second, count the number of ways to put the $n$ balls in the $n-1$ other boxes, so that each box reveives at least one ball. This amounts to finding the number of *surjections* from a set of $n$ elements to a set $n-1$ elements.

In such a surjection one element of the target (one box) receives exactly $2$ elements from the source ($2$ balls), and the remaining $n-2$ elements/boxes receive exactly one element. In other words, a surjection from a set of $n$ elements to a set of $n-1$ elements can be defined thus:

1. First,choose in the source the pair of elements (balls) that will have the same image (go into the same box). There are $\dbinom n2$ such pairs.
2. Second,, choose the box that will accomodate these two balls. There are $n-1$ choices.
3. Third, establish a bijection between the $n-2$ remaining elements of the source (remaining balls) and the $n-2$ remaining elements of the target (remaining balls). There are $(n-2)!$ of these bijections;

The number of such arrangements  is then:

$$n\,\binom n2(n-1)\cdot (n-2)!=\binom n2\, n!$$

The whole set of possibilities can be modelled as all maps from a set of $n$ lelements to a set of $n-1$ elements. There are $n^n$ of them.

We can now compute $P$:
$$P=\frac{\dbinom n2\mkern1.5mu n!}{n^n}=\frac{(n-1)\mkern1.5mu n!}{2\mkern1.5mu n^{n-1}}$$